# User uid incrementing in non sequential manner

Tags: 6, users

I have a drupal site that has been running for about 1 year. there are about 1000 members in the users table

recently I have noticed something very strange the Users uid field is no longer inrementing sequentially.

It now jumps up in the 10s, for example, my last 8 users, the uids went from 7999 to 8068, 8094, 8350, 8416, 8458, 8534, 8566.

So sometimes it is jumping 100s at a time.

How can I work out what might be causing this, and should I be worried?

Comment: Can users create their own accounts? Do you have a  CAPTCHA preventing automated user registration spam?

Comment: Seems to me it's nothing to do with 10's but just random jumps.

Comment: Are you definitely using drupal 6 as per the tags on this post or are you on drupal 7?

Comment: Yes, system is built on Drupal 6 and you're right, its not in 10s exactly, I just meant that it does not increment in single iterations. Users can create their own accounts, but there is a table of application requests that records the details of a Users account creation and there are no corresponding entries for the missing uids. It should not be possible to create a user account without it being registered in the requests table.

Comment: Here's your answer http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/42739/7641. I guess that makes this question a duplicate.

Comment: That answer is to do with Drupal 7. The issue Im having is with Drupal 6. And it has only started recently, the first 1000 or so uids were sequential

Comment: Sorry. When did the last sequential user register? Did you update Drupal (or change anything else) around that time?

Comment: Has any module manipulated the schema definition for the users table?

Answer (score 1):

If it is exactly 10 then it might have to do with MySQL's Auto Increment value
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686327/change-the-step-auto-increment-fields-increment-by

drupal.org currently uses this feature for master slave replication. Right now all users and nodes being created have a odd value. If you look further back this value was EVEN at one point.

Comment: ITs not in even amounts of 10 as can be seen from the sequence I posted in the question