# Auto Increment - Order/user numbers not changing

Tags: 7, database

I've executed the following via phpmyAdmin but nether the order nor user numbers change.

```
ALTER TABLE 'users' AUTO_INCREMENT = 1025;
ALTER TABLE 'commerce_order' AUTO_INCREMENT = 1025;
```

I checked inside 'commerce_order' and the AUTO INCREMENT is set to: 1025(order numbers should change).
When i check inside the 'users' table, AUTO INCREMENT is NOT available(why?).

I've cleared the cache.
Shouldn't this be working?
Drupal7

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The users table does not work with AUTO INCREMENT in Drupal 7.
Instead, the ids are generated in PHP.

See [What could cause uids to not be numbered consecutively?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40181/what-could-cause-uids-to-not-be-numbered-consecutively/42739#42739)

Comment: So....it looks like it is not possible to do what i want? Or at least, not possible to do a quick modification(like the auto increment specify)?